# Why these two statements have different results?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select a.id,a.parent from qa a left join qa b on a.parent=b.parent where b.id=7;
+----+--------+
| id | parent |
+----+--------+
|  7 |      1 |
|  8 |      1 |
|  9 |      1 |
+----+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select a.id,a.parent from qa a left join qa b on a.parent=b.parent and b.id=7;
+----+--------+
| id | parent |
+----+--------+
|  1 |   NULL |
|  2 |   NULL |
|  3 |   NULL |
|  4 |   NULL |
|  5 |   NULL |
|  6 |   NULL |
|  7 |      1 |
|  8 |      1 |
|  9 |      1 |
+----+--------+
```

I read them exactly the same!

Comment: What's in the table? `select * from qa`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first statement will create the join, and then filter the result using *WHERE b.id=7*.

So only rows from **a** where **a.parent=b.parent** and that join result has **b.id=7**.

The second statement will create the left join with the *b.id=7*, thus including all rows from *qa a*, and then only values from *qa b* where *b.id=7*.

So all rows from **a** where **a.parent=b.parent**, but show values from **b** only where **b.id=7**

Answer (score 0):

you first query is limiting the right hand side of your result by automatically eliminating the `NULLs` that a `LEFT JOIN` can/will return. The statementds would return the same results if you were using an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

First has a condition (`where`) on the select statement, second applies b.id condition on the join.

From the docs:

> If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for the right table.